# Initializing issue in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have made a custom ViewController that is `MBTextViewController`. When i make an instance of this class like this

```
self.topTextView = [[MBTextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MBTextViewController" bundle:nil];
self.topTextView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.topTextView.view.frame.size.width, self.topTextView.view.frame.size.height);
[self.mainContainerView addSubview:self.topTextView.view];
```

its work well and all the pan guestures work fine.

But, when I try to instantiate it at runtime, the app crashed when I try to move the object.

```
MBTextViewController *textView = [[MBTextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MBTextViewController" bundle:nil];
textView.view.center = self.mainContainerView.center;

[self.mainContainerView addSubview:textView.view];
```

By the way here is my panGuesture recognizer function

```
CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:[self.view superview]];
CGPoint viewPosition = self.view.center;
viewPosition.x += translation.x;
viewPosition.y += translation.y;
self.view.center = viewPosition;
[panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
```

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown any code related to your gesture, the crash stack trace and message or given a real description of the difference in what you do when it doesn't work. We need all those details...

Comment: it goes to the main function and told for bad access.The only issue i can find is the objects created on runtime are not global.

Answer (score 1):

Bad access would suggest the gesture is sending a message to a deallocated object. I think textView is no longer in memory when the gesture fires. In the first example, textView is a property i.e.

```
self.topTextView = [[MBTextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MBTextViewController" bundle:nil];
```

In the second example, you are just a creating a local variable which is most likely being deallocted. Make textView a property again and see if that helps.

Of course, this all assumes that the gestures's delegate is the MBTextViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add your view controller as child view controller.

```
MBTextViewController *textView = [[MBTextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MBTextViewController" bundle:nil];
textView.view.center = self.mainContainerView.center;

[self addChildViewController:textView];
[self.mainContainerView addSubview:textView.view];
```

**Here is the reason:**
When you create a view controller in a method. Score of the view controller is local only. As the program control reaches to end of method, it deallocates the view controller. 
iOS SDK encourages to add child view controller for child views.
Same thing can be done by using ContainerView in StoryBoard.

Comment: Welcome Mayank. You can give me plus one and choose this as correct answer.

Comment: Yes i will give you but till now my reputation is only 11.

Comment: Although this solves the issue it doesn't explain why. Error was occurring to deallocation of textView object. With your solution it's now retained by parentViewController as a child. It works just fine, but the answer teaches you nothing and encourages [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that your controller is deallocated when you are trying to get a callback for gesture. When you instantiate controller like this:

```
MBTextViewController *textView = [[MBTextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MBTextViewController" bundle:nil];
```

It is only retained at the current  scope and is released at the end of the method/function. This is why you get a bad access error. It needs to have at least 1 strong reference to stay in memory. Making `textView` a `@property (strong)` will do the trick